# floating-point running sum doesn't move

Tags: pascal, freepascal

eeh the good ,the bad and the ugly
why `round(cargof)` stays at `2` ?

```pascal
uses crt;

type 
    trail_type = (blue ,desert ,white);
    fruit_class = (none ,apple ,pineapple);
type
    ontherun = Record
    trail : trail_type;
    cargo : Integer;
    miles : Integer;
end;
Var 
    b : File of ontherun;
    rec : ontherun;
    rec_b : array[1..3] of ontherun;
    k , cargo , load , xload , miles , run : Integer;
    cargof  : Double;
    fruit : fruit_class;

begin
        cargof := 0;
        Repeat
            cargof := 0.04*cargof + 2.0;
            Writeln(round(cargof)); 
        Until cargof > 223;
writeln('hi');  
end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you output your intermediate calculations of cargof (before rounding), it appears that the value is converging on 2.08333333333333.

I guess a way to think of it is that you're adding 4% each time, but it's 4% of the difference between each result, not a compound 4% of the total.

Comment: it's pmt compound

Comment: I don't know much about calculus, but if you're trying to get a compound increase, do you maybe mean 1.04 rather than 0.04?

Comment: more clear is `cargof := cargof + 0.04*cargof + 2.0;`

Comment: because you have first one on account and other two go there each time

Answer (score 5):

Actually, this has nothing to do specifically with FreePascal. And not Pascal. And not floating-point numbers. And not computer programming. Not even computers.

It's pure math.

We have the recurrence relation *a*(0) = 0, *a*(*n* + 1) = (1/25) *a*(*n*) + 2.

With the ansatz *a*(*n*) = α + β *k*^*n* we find that *a*(*n* + 1) = α + β *k*^(*n* + 1) = α + β *k* *k*^*n* = α + *k*(*a*(*n*) − α) = α − *k* α + *k* *a*(*n*) because *a*(*n*) − α = β *k*^*n*. This should be equal to 2 + (1/25) *a*(*n*) for all non-negative values of *n*, which means that *k* = 1/25 and α − *k* α = 2 which implies α = 25/12. Finally, *a*(0) = 0 yields β = −25/12.

Therefore, *a*(*n*) = (25/12) (1 − 1/25^*n*) for all non-negative *n*.

It is easily verified that this is indeed a solution and that *a*(*n*) → 25/12 as *n* → ∞; specifically, *a*(*n*) grows monotonically to this limit.

Now, 25/12 = 2.08333333333.... so rounded to the nearest integer the value will never exceed 2.

Comment: spot  it now `cargof :=cargof + 0.04*cargof + 2.0;`

Comment: Much the better answer, imo, +1.  Let's hope no-one objects that your analysis proves that the q is off-topic!